# Create fat runnable jar for spark-submit

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, executable-jar, spark-submit

I'm writing a Spark application using Java(not Scala).
Something like:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TEST");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
sc.setLogLevel("WARN");
```

I started with simple java project and when to compile the project into a runnable jar for SPARK-SUBMIT, I simply right click the project and export like pic1 below

[pic1, export the runnable jar and extract req. libs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCFcB.png)

[pic2, what it is like in the runnable jar with all libs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7mKR.png)

[pic3, MANIFEST.MF file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQe4m.png)

And it functioned well.

Then I tried to reorganized it into a Maven project. I intended to package the project into a jar with req. lib included and NOT nested as well.
And below is part in pom.xml

```html
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes><exclude>**/dqci.properties</exclude></excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.walmart.china.mdmDqci.DQCIApplicatoin</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

[pic4, what it looks like in the new jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Enm4s.png)

[pic5, new MANIFEST.MF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A63W9.png)

However, when I ran the jar in the same env, exceptions was shown like below:

```html
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.walmart.china.Main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:175)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:689)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

My assumption is that I didn't use the right plug-in for my project. Any suggestions on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks you are missing a dependency...